# ValidationError when sparse updating a Payment trying to specify new LinkedTxn lines

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am trying to perform a [sparse update](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0300_developer_guides/0015_calling_data_services#Sparse_updating) on a QuickBooks Online Payment object using the .NET SDK. For some reason as soon as I try to specify a `<Line>` element in the update request, I get a ValidationError requiring a CustomerRef.

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Payment xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" sparse="true" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
  <Id>1060</Id>
  <SyncToken>3</SyncToken>
  <TxnDate>2014-11-25</TxnDate>
  <PrivateNote />
  <Line>
    <Amount>390.0000</Amount>
    <LinkedTxn>
      <TxnId>1308</TxnId>
      <TxnType>Invoice</TxnType>
    </LinkedTxn>
  </Line>
  <TotalAmt>390.0000</TotalAmt>
</Payment>
```

Response:

```
{"Fault": {
    "Error": [{
        "Message":"Required param missing, need to supply the required value for the API",
        "Detail":"Required parameter CustomerRef is missing in the request",
        "code":"2020",
        "element":"Payment"}],
    "type":"ValidationFault"},
"time":"2015-01-20T07:20:15.191-08:00"}
```

I thought a sparse update meant that anything you did not specify stayed the same as the original entity. I can't see anything that says one way or the other in the [documentation](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/payment). Do I need to fetch the CustomerRef from the current entity to feed it back to the API and keep it happy, or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is Sparse update but I believe the customerref is required, as a 'validation check for Customer' is needed when you send the Update request. This check is needed to verify that CustomerRef for Updated payment is same as the Invoice's CustomerRef. So, you should send it in your request.

Comment: Hmm, that would certainly explain why it all of a sudden becomes necessary when I start sending a replacement `Line[]`. I wonder why, since it forces an extra query to retrieve the customer id and spit it back to the API when QBO could just get it internally without traversing the internet.